# What is best practice for instance attribute assignment?

Tags: python, class, methods

Given two approaches to working with classes, I'd like to know which approach is more 'standard' or even 'better'?

##### Assign attribute in method

```
class ChildFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, fields=None, **options):
        super().__init__(parent, **options)
        self.fields = fields
        self.field_width()

    def field_width(self):
        self.fw = max(map(len, self.vars))
```

##### Assign attribute by method return

```
class ChildFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, fields=None, **options):
        super().__init__(parent, **options)
        self.fields = fields
        self.fw = self.field_width()

    def field_width(self):
        return max(map(len, self.vars))
```

As a non-programmer/learner, I'd like to know your reasoning why, or thoughts on when to use one or the other.

Comment: FYI I updated the title in your question bc "class attributes" are actually something specific in Python that are different from what you're asking about (instance attributes).  However, I think this question is probably subjective/opinionated.  If it were me I'd do the latter, because a method that computes that value should probably return that value rather than assign it to an attribute.  You may also want to look into [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) and [`cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property)

Comment: Probably opinon-based, but #2 makes `field_width` more generally applicable, as the caller gets to decide if an attribute is set.

Comment: Opinion-based (or at least extremely context-dependent), because what is a property setter if not a method that sets an instance attribute? :)

Comment: @chepner: I'd argue that's fine as long as the attribute it wraps is set in `__init__` (either through the `property`, or directly). Either way, you're not worried about whether there are phantom attributes that you missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the assignment in `__init__`. Someone looking at your class should be able to determine from `__init__` alone the set of all attributes instances of the class can have (in a subclassing case, they have to check the ancestor `__init__`s as well, but at least they don't have to check *every* method of *every* ancestor), without searching every method called by it in case they set additional attributes.

Even lazily defined attributes should be set to a placeholder in `__init__`, both for readability, and because it allows [the key-sharing dictionary optimization](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/) to work (reducing per-instance memory usage significantly).